# How to get dynamic data in bootstrap modal for each id by using laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel-5

I am developing an app which requires to show the data at every click on my different list of icon. The problem is how to display data in to bootstrap modal according to id. Thanks in advance.
index.blade.php .

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="{{$post->id}}">Ajouter
  </button>
 </div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId"
  aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" >
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

```
                <div class="modal-body" >
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12 ">
                                 <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">Nouvelle annonce</div>
                                         <div class=" form-group col-sm-6">
                                            <img class="cart-img img-responsive" src="images/cover_image/{{$post->cover_image}}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                                         </div>
                                        <div class=" form-group col-sm-3">
                                             <span id="layer_cart_product_title" class="product-name layer_cart_product_title"><h2> {{$post->nom_comr}}</h2> </span>
                                                <hr>
                                            <span id="layer_cart_product_ti" class="product-name"><h4> &nbsp;{{$post->date_perm}}</h4> </span>
                                            <span id="layer_cart_product_ti" class="product-name"><h4> &nbsp;{{$post->offre}}</h4> </span>
                                                    <hr>
                                             <span id="layer_cart_product_ti" class="product-name"><h4> &nbsp;{{$post->pv_ht}}</h4> </span>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: it depends on your preference, since it can be tackled in many ways, if you're not fetching a lot of items, like only 4 or 8 at a time, you can prefetch them already. you could also go the ajax route. pass the id to the server, server uses id to select based on id, server responds back with a json string with all the details, frontend receives it and then puts everything in the markup

Comment: Call a function where get the id of record and pass through `Ajax` so you get data of related id then bind to your modal and open modal using `Jquery` or `JS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by passing the post id in data-target and also in midel in

```
    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$post->id}}">Ajouter </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="{{$post->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$post->id}}" data-id="{{$post->id}}">Ajouter</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$post->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
```

thats work for me

Comment: Great job worked for me too, thanks Mitra!